# PostGIS transform geometry with long crs

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

How do i transform a geometry to a new geometry with a crs like `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832`

`st_transform(geom,integer srid)` obviously doesn't work since my srid is a string

found a solution

```
ST_Transform(geom,
             ST_SRID(
                     ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
                       '{"type":"POINT",
                         "coordinates":[0,0],
                         "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832"}}}'
                        )
                    )
                )
```

Comment: Your solution only works if the crs is already listed in spatial_ref_sys table. `ST_Transform(geom,25832)` would be the same.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. It's good to solve your own problems, and best for all of us if you post the solution as an Answer, not in the Q.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enter the CRS definition into the `spatial_ref_sys` table of postgis, giving it a unique SRID. Then you can use that in all functions.

Usually, all EPSG codes are already in there.

Comment: thx but im developing a REST service to transform geometrys and since the crs is a user input i dont want to add a bunch of custom crs definitions

Comment: @thegrouch -- It's also best if you edit the new requirements/info (user inputs CRS) into the question.

Comment: Is it a recommended way to add support for new CRS definitions - adding them manually to `spatial_ref_sys` table?